# sql query simplify?

Tags: sql

I have to pull data from a database table based on the result from another table.
First I'll mention the tables and what they're for.

**db_vehicles** - This table is a database of all the vehicles. It contains name, shortname, speed, and other info. (Eg, name=Sports Car, shortname=sports, speed=10)

Sample;

```
id        name       shortname      speed    
 1    'Sports Car'    'sports'        7
```

**items_vehicles** = This table keeps a record of the players cars, each column being a shortname for each car in db_vehicles. (eg trucks=5, sports=8, bikes=3)

Sample;

```
id    player    bike    sports    truck
1       1        5        7         0
```

---

Basically what I need to do is check that the player actually owns the vehicle he has 'equipped' ($vehicle). This checks the items_vehicles table, but to find the column in that table it needs to check the db_vehicles table first, to get the 'shortname'.

Heres the code I currently use:

```
$vehicle = "Sports Car"; // example

if ($vehicle != "") { //if the players has a vehicle 'equipped'

    $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT shortname FROM db_vehicles WHERE name='$vehicle'", $db);  
    $rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);

    //we have the shortname, now check to see if he has any

    $sql_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_vehicles WHERE player='$id'", $db);
    $rs3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result3);

    // now if he has none, make $vehicle empty

    if ($rs3[$rs2[shortname]] < 1) { 
        $vehicle="";
        }
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe with one query using subqueries or anything?

The reason I need one is because I do this with four times on each page load, it checks vehicles, weapon, equipment, and melee. (Its for a game script)

### update

I tried using something like this, but doesnt work:

```
 $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_vehicles WHERE items_vehicles.(SELECT shortname FROM db_vehicles WHERE name='$vehicle')=db_vehicles.shortname WHERE items_vehicles.player='$id'", $db);
```

Comment: Maybe if you provide a full field list for both tables and an example row set for each.  There may be a foreign key you could join on or something.  Its not not clear if that is the case based on the limited information in the question.

Comment: updated original post to show that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the exact database that you are using, but a general SQL solution is an inner join (this will be using SQL Server syntax):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM items_vehicles
 WHERE player='$id'
   AND 1 >= CASE (SELECT shortname 
                   FROM db_vehicles
                  WHERE name='$vehicle') 
                WHEN 'sports' THEN sports
                WHEN 'bike' THEN bike
                // add more here
                ELSE 0
           END
```

Comment: there's no 'items_vehicles.shortname'. All the columns in items_vehicles are named after shortnames of the vehicles, eg "sports", "bike", "truck", etc.

Comment: Ah, how many columns do you have? Do you have the ability to redesign the table?

Comment: in items_vehicles i have probably 10 columns, one for each vehicle, an id, and a player column.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to show retrieving the data in a single query. Basically, the where statement retrieves the appropriate column based on the short name and evaluates it against 1, which means that the were statement will only return a value when there is a non-zero value in the corresponding column.

Comment: ah i see. So everytime I add a new item to my game i'd have to update this code.. Ok thanks.